# Ajax and loop in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new in Ajax, and I'm trying to create an Ajax call for a lot of div..
Let's say I have a dom like this :

```
    <div id="form">
        <div id="child_1">
            <div id="child_1_select"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="child_2">
            <div id="child_2_select"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="child_3">
            <div id="child_3_select"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="child_4">
            <div id="child_4_select"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
```

How do I proceed to loop in `#form` ?
Because I would like to have an Ajax call for all of the `child_x_select`.

Btw, I don't know how many `#child_x_select` there'll be, because the user can add as many divs as he needs...

Many thanks for considering my request !

Comment: If you have a greater amount of content to request, it could be better to combine it into one single request. But that belongs to the usecase. Could you give us more details to a most best answer here?

Comment: do you want to loop like this         $('#form div[id^=child_][id$=_select]').each(function(){ //code goes here });

Comment: @eisbehr No I don't want to combine it into one single request, because in a `#child_n_div` there'll be 2 select, with one which depend on the other...

Comment: use `name="somename[]"` property, to have an array for all div data

Answer (score 1):

You should consider adding a common class to your `#child_n_select` elements, and use jQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method on it :

```
<div id="form">
    <div id="child_1">
        <div id="child_1_select" class="child_select"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child_2">
        <div id="child_2_select" class="child_select"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child_3">
        <div id="child_3_select" class="child_select"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child_4">
        <div id="child_4_select" class="child_select"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.child_select').each(function() {
        // Write your AJAX call here, using $(this) to select the active element.
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you need to select all of the `child_x_select` elements after an ajax call? You would simply register the selector on the callback.

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = function(e) {

  // load all of the children using ajax

  // select the children
  var children = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_select"]');
  // convert to array and loop
  Array.prototype.slice.call(children).forEach(function(node){
    // do some wacky stuff here
  });
}
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

But if you're simply saying you need to loop over each element, this is all you need:

```
var children = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="_select"]');

Array.prototype.slice.call(children).forEach(function(node){
  // do some wacky stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the ajax call for creating `divs` and assign id names in `child_x_select` format using index(i) value.

```
$.ajax ({
            type:"GET",
            url: myUrl,
            success:function(data){
                for i in data {
                  $('form').append("<div id='child_"+[i]+"_select'></div>");
                }
        };
```